# Celery is not updating django model field

Tags: django, celery

So I have written a celery task to update a field on my django model which is here

```
class PizzaOrder(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to update the order_status as following

- Once the order is placed, in the first minute, the status should change from ‘Placed’ to ‘Accepted’
- After 1 minute, the status should change from ‘Accepted’ to ‘Preparing’
- After 3 minutes it should change from ‘Preparing’ to ‘Dispatched’
- After 5 minutes it should read ‘Delivered’

for which I have written below celery task

```
from celery import shared_task
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import PizzaOrder

@shared_task
def update_order_status(order_id):
    try:
        order = PizzaOrder.objects.get(pk=order_id)
        current_time = timezone.now()
        
        if order.order_status == 'Placed' and current_time - order.created_at <= timedelta(minutes=1):
            order.order_status = 'Accepted'
        elif order.order_status == 'Accepted' and current_time - order.created_at > timedelta(minutes=1) and current_time - order.created_at <= timedelta(minutes=2):
            order.order_status = 'Preparing'
        elif order.order_status == 'Preparing' and current_time - order.created_at > timedelta(minutes=3) and current_time - order.created_at <= timedelta(minutes=5):
            order.order_status = 'Dispatched'
        elif order.order_status == 'Dispatched' and current_time - order.created_at > timedelta(minutes=5):
            order.order_status = 'Delivered'
        
        order.save()
    except PizzaOrder.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

And I am calling that method in serializer once I am saving the serializer object which is as follows:

```
class PizzaOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pizzas = PizzaSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PizzaOrder
        fields = ["customer", "pizzas", "total_price"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pizzas_data = validated_data.pop('pizzas')
        request = self.context.get('request')
        total_price = len(pizzas_data) * 69  # Calculate the total price based on the number of pizzas
        order_status = "Placed"
        pizza_order = PizzaOrder.objects.create(customer=request.user, total_price=total_price, order_status=order_status, **validated_data)

        update_order_status.apply_async(args=[pizza_order.id], countdown=0)
```

but its not updating the value off of it as i required,can anyone help me out with the missing link why its not happening

My server is running fine as I got this status

```
[2023-09-28 02:19:29,116: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2023-09-28 02:19:29,116: WARNING/MainProcess] /Users/kartikeysinha/Desktop/local-git-repository/git-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:507: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
  warnings.warn(

[2023-09-28 02:19:29,119: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-09-28 02:19:30,133: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-09-28 02:19:30,152: INFO/MainProcess] celery@Kartikeys-MacBook-Air.local ready.
[2023-09-28 02:19:42,576: INFO/MainProcess] Task api.tasks.update_order_status[e8095710-77b5-4738-8fe8-05a12895f3eb] received
[2023-09-28 02:19:42,660: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task api.tasks.update_order_status[e8095710-77b5-4738-8fe8-05a12895f3eb] succeeded in 0.08167616600000116s: None
```

Any help would be great ,
Thanks & Regards

Comment: The task works, but one of the conditions is not met which prevents updating the status, try debugging the task, print the variables to a console or reload the celery worker, because everytime you change your code base celery doesn't know about the changes

Comment: You are calling celery job only once. So order status may be as 'Accepted' always.